# Edit page shown after login in Wordpress?

Tags: pages, login

I am currently using the wp_login hook to run a php function when a user logins. However, I want to show users who login notifications (a pop up with recent posts, etc) and I was planning to do this by running a javascript function.

Is it possible to edit the page shown to the user after login?

This is the code I have so far:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'my_login_function' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'the_footer_function' );

function the_footer_function(){
    if (defined('FIRST_RUN')){
        echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready( function(){alert('hello');});</script>";
        define('FIRST_RUN', false);
    }
}

function my_login_function($user_login){
     global $altdb;
     $user_info = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
     $wonAwards = $altdb->get_var("SELECT achievement_id FROM user_".$user_info->ID." WHERE isTold='false'");
     define('FIRST_RUN', true);
     //$altdb->query("UPDATE user_".$user_info->ID." SET isTold='true' WHERE isTold = false") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter( "login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3 );
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    return home_url( "/your_page/" );
}
```

Should about do it for you. Modified from a script that I had running in wp3.3.1.

Docs: [`home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url), [`login_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

Answer (score 0):

you may try using the wp_redirect() function, I was doing that in the past but I don't know how it will behave in the recent releases (in theory it should work)